# login form doesn't redirect

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

My login from doesn't redirect me on my index page. I need help.

Here is my index.php

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

include "includes/dbh.inc.php";
include "includes/user.inc.php";
include "includes/login.inc.php";
    session_start();
    $query = new Login();
    $query->userLogin($_POST['name'], $_POST['password']);

    if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true) {

        echo "Welcome to the member's area, " . $_SESSION['email'] . "!";
    } else {
        echo "Please log in first to see this page.";
    }

 ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>News | DanneggiastaCraft</title>
    <meta name="description" content="The Danneggisata Craft">
    <meta name="DanneggiastaCraft" content="News">

    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css">

    <!-- Font -->
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans|Baumans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

</head>
<body>


<!-- Site Wrapper -->
<div class="site-wrapper" id="page-top">
    <header class="main-header">

        <div class="header-logo">

            <h1>DanneggiastaCraft</h1>

            <p>World News</p>

        </div>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.php" class="current">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Tech</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sport</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Weather</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <!-- Body Wrapper -->
    <div class="body-wrapper" id="main-section">

        <section id="news">
            <div class="fourth">
                <img src="assets/img/news.jpg">

                <h3>Phasellus lorem erat, fringilla vestibulum est sit amet, lobortis tincidunt leo. Nam non
                    posuere lorem.</h3>

                <p>Nulla vitae ultricies metus, sed consequat elit. Suspendisse nisl velit, cursus sed mattis a, varius
                    sit amet nibh. Cras imperdiet nulla vitae euismod blandit. Sed pulvinar nibh ut dolor semper
                    accumsan. Phasellus lorem erat, fringilla vestibulum est sit amet, lobortis tincidunt leo. Nam non
                    posuere lorem. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis
                    egestas. Nunc scelerisque, odio eu efficitur commodo, tortor tellus accumsan magna, ut eleifend sem
                    velit vitae sapien. Donec nec ornare mi, sit amet mollis neque. Donec mattis sapien elit, at
                    hendrerit diam suscipit in. In molestie ut diam vitae luctus. Duis neque lorem, ultricies eu elit
                    vitae, malesuada varius arcu. Suspendisse lobortis blandit orci sit amet mattis.</p>

            </div>

            <div class="fourth">
                <img src="assets/img/news.jpg">

                <h3>Nulla vitae ultricies metus, sed consequat elit. Suspendisse nisl velit, cursus sed mattis a, varius
                    sit amet nibh. Cras imperdiet nulla vitae euismod blandit. Sed pulvinar nibh ut dolor semper
                    accumsan. Phasellus lorem erat, fringilla vestibulum est</h3>

                <p>Nulla vitae ultricies metus, sed consequat elit. Suspendisse nisl velit, cursus sed mattis a, varius
                    sit amet nibh. Cras imperdiet nulla vitae euismod blandit. Sed pulvinar nibh ut dolor semper
                    accumsan. Phasellus lorem erat, fringilla vestibulum est sit amet, lobortis tincidunt leo. Nam non
                    posuere lorem. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis
                    egestas. Nunc scelerisque, odio eu efficitur commodo, tortor tellus accumsan magna, ut eleifend sem
                    velit vitae sapien. Donec nec ornare mi, sit amet mollis neque. Donec mattis sapien elit, at
                    hendrerit diam suscipit in. In molestie ut diam vitae luctus. Duis neque lorem, ultricies eu elit
                    vitae, malesuada varius arcu. Suspendisse lobortis blandit orci sit amet mattis.</p>

            </div>

            <div class="fourth">
                <img src="assets/img/news.jpg">

                <h3>Comtrade prvi na svetu lansirao bankarsku aplikaciju za VIBER!.</h3>

                <p>Nulla vitae ultricies metus, sed consequat elit. Suspendisse nisl velit, cursus sed mattis a, varius
                    sit amet nibh. Cras imperdiet nulla vitae euismod blandit. Sed pulvinar nibh ut dolor semper
                    accumsan. Phasellus lorem erat, fringilla vestibulum est sit amet, lobortis tincidunt leo. Nam non
                    posuere lorem. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis
                    egestas. Nunc scelerisque, odio eu efficitur commodo, tortor tellus accumsan magna, ut eleifend sem
                    velit vitae sapien. Donec nec ornare mi, sit amet mollis neque. Donec mattis sapien elit, at
                    hendrerit diam suscipit in. In molestie ut diam vitae luctus. Duis neque lorem, ultricies eu elit
                    vitae, malesuada varius arcu. Suspendisse lobortis blandit orci sit amet mattis.</p>

            </div>

            <div class="fourth">
                <img src="assets/img/news.jpg">

                <h3>Comtrade prvi na svetu lansirao bankarsku aplikaciju za VIBER!.</h3>

                <p>Nulla vitae ultricies metus, sed consequat elit. Suspendisse nisl velit, cursus sed mattis a, varius
                    sit amet nibh. Cras imperdiet nulla vitae euismod blandit. Sed pulvinar nibh ut dolor semper
                    accumsan. Phasellus lorem erat, fringilla vestibulum est sit amet, lobortis tincidunt leo. Nam non
                    posuere lorem. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis
                    egestas. Nunc scelerisque, odio eu efficitur commodo, tortor tellus accumsan magna, ut eleifend sem
                    velit vitae sapien. Donec nec ornare mi, sit amet mollis neque. Donec mattis sapien elit, at
                    hendrerit diam suscipit in. In molestie ut diam vitae luctus. Duis neque lorem, ultricies eu elit
                    vitae, malesuada varius arcu. Suspendisse lobortis blandit orci sit amet mattis.</p>

            </div>
        </section>

        <aside>
            <div class="form-wrapper">

                <form action="includes/login.inc.php" id="login">

                    <h2>Login</h2>
                    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your Email"><br>
                    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Your Password"><br>

                    <input type="submit" value="Log In">
                </form>

                <form id="register">

                    <h2>Register New Account</h2>
                    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your Name"><br>
                    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Email"><br>
                    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Your Password"><br>

                    <input type="submit" value="Register">

                </form>
            </div>
        </aside>
    </div>
    <!-- End Body Wrapper -->

    <footer>

        <p>Copyright &copy; DanneggiastaCraft 2017.</p>

    </footer>
</div>
<!-- End Site Wrapper -->
</body>
</html>
```

my db connection code:

```
<?php

class Dbh {

    private $servername;
    private $username;
    private $password;
    private $dbname;

    protected function connect() {

        $this->servername = "localhost";
        $this->username = "danneggiasta";
        $this->password = "";
        $this->dbname = "news";

        $conn = new mysqli($this->servername, $this->username, $this->password, $this->dbname);

        // Check connection
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        } else {
            echo "Connected successfully";
            return $conn;
        }
    }
}
```

my login.php:

```
<?php

require_once('dbh.inc.php');

class Login extends Dbh {

private $email;
private $pass;

public function userLogin($email, $pass) {

    $conn = parent::connect();


    if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
        $email = $_POST['name'];
    }

    if (isset($_POST['password'])) {
        $pass = $_POST['password'];
    }

    $r = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email' and pass='$pass'");

    // If result matched $username and $password, table row must be 1 row
    if ($r->num_rows == 1) {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
        $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
        header('Location: http://www.google.com');
    }
 }
}
```

I would really appreciate any help that u can provide. where did I made a mistake? What is wrong? And if you have any suggestion where I should change my code I will be happy to hear it.

Comment: Errors? Please enable error reporting so we can diagnose your issue.

Comment: Ok i see that i haven;t made a call to my Login function, so i have added it and also i deleted strpslashes cause its old.

Comment: Hey @tomUdding whrere to enable it?

Comment: is this filepath and filename correct? `action="includes/login.inc.php"`

Comment: Well, if you didn't invoke `Login()` it won't work (please update your code in the question). See [How do I get PHP errors to display?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1053424/5914775) to see how you can enable error reporting.

Comment: @tomudding i got this from errors: Notice: Undefined index: email in C:\xampp\htdocs\vesti\includes\login.inc.php on line 14

Notice: Undefined index: pass in C:\xampp\htdocs\vesti\includes\login.inc.php on line 15

Comment: @chinito yeah that path is ok

Comment: @NebojsaZlatanovic pass the `$_POST` variables as parameters in the `userLogin()` function.

Comment: when i click login i get empty page

Comment: make sure your email and pass is not empty and check if that data is correct in your database. try using `var_dump()`

Comment: data is correct in database, and where do u think i should put var_dump()?

Comment: @chinito can u connect with teamviewer to see what is going on?

Comment: your error should be on the query. you don't have any error right? or anything that printed on your screen?

Comment: not any error just blank page

Comment: are you sure you called this `userLogin` function? if yes, then you should have a printed text on the page. either `Connection failed` or `Connected successfully`

Comment: <?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);


include "includes/dbh.inc.php";
include "includes/user.inc.php";
include "includes/login.inc.php";

session_start();
$query = new Login();

if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
    
    $query->userLogin($_POST['name'], $_POST['password']);
} else {

    echo 'ahafffasgsgasdgsagsgss';
}

?>

Comment: i have tryed everything i rly dont know what to do. Please help me.

Comment: i don't know your filenames. so it's really difficult to determine the error. `<form action="includes/login.inc.php" id="login" method="POST">` so the filename should be `login.inc.php` and in your `login.inc.php` file rename `include "includes/login.inc.php";` to `
  include "includes/login.php";` to include your `Login` class

Comment: i've got index.php -- main page
dbh.inc.php --- db connection
login.inc.php --- here is class and method userLogin

Comment: one weird thing to me -> you include `includes/login.inc.php` on top of index.php then link it in the `form action` ?

Comment: @oldpadawan so? what u mean i should do?

Comment: whatever i do i get blank page

Comment: can someone help me???????????????????

Comment: @chinito hey man i noticed in login.inc.php my $r = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * WHERE email='$email' AND pass='$pass' FROM users");

        var_dump($r); -- shows bool(false) error

Comment: it should be `$r = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email' and pass='$pass'");`. did you connect successfully?

Comment: hm in the end i made it !!! thank you a lot.

Answer (score -2):

```
<form action="includes/login.php" id="login">
```